# How to make Oracle 'order by' behave like SQLServer?

Tags: oracle, sorting

i'm trying to write an Oracle query that sorts the results in the same way as MS SQL Server does. I'm toying with the ['NLSSORT'](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2038.htm) function and it's parameters but i can't get exactly the same results as what i can see with MS SQL Server.

The context is a generic data collection system that supports both Oracle and MS SQL Server. This is a pretty old system that is still under maintenance and development. No entity framework or any recent approaches to handle database interactions.

With a simple order by on MS SQL Server i get this result:

_TEST
04-00031-IPE
04-00044-OG
0A-A
A0-A
SAZ2217

The same query on Oracle returns this:

04-00031-IPE
04-00044-OG
0A-A
A0-A
SAZ2217
_TEST

I have tried many combinations of NLSSORT parameters without any success.

[edit]
By using the 'PUNCTUATION' NLS_SORT parameter value, i get results very close to the MS SQL sorting but there is still differences with substrings that contains sequences of numeric chars. Here is a sample query result:

Oracle
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-AV-AP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-AV-SP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-SV-AP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-SV-SP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC10-DV-AP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC10-DV-SP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC2-DV-AP

Ms SQL
0031-CASTOR-BLOC10-DV-AP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC10-DV-SP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-AV-AP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-AV-SP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-SV-AP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-SV-SP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC2-DV-AP

Thank you for your help!

Comment: so what parameters have you specified so far? Looks like it is using ascii. Possible changing to English would help.

Comment: English seems to have been disabled by the DBA i guess. If i use:

 ORDER BY NLSSORT(RESULTATS_DERNIER_MES.UNE_CODE_IDENT, 'NLS_SORT=FRENCH') 

Oracle handles it (although i get the wrong sorting) but if i use:

 ORDER BY NLSSORT(RESULTATS_DERNIER_MES.UNE_CODE_IDENT, 'NLS_SORT=ENGLISH') 

i get an Oracle error ora-12702.

I have also tried 

'NLS_SORT = BINARY NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC'

Comment: (sorry for dups)

English seems to have been disabled by the DBA i guess. If i use:  

 ORDER BY NLSSORT(RESULTATS_DERNIER_MES.UNE_CODE_IDENT, 'NLS_SORT=FRENCH') 

Oracle handles it (although i get the wrong sorting) but if i use:  

 ORDER BY NLSSORT(RESULTATS_DERNIER_MES.UNE_CODE_IDENT, 'NLS_SORT=ENGLISH') 

i get an Oracle error ora-12702.

I have also tried   

'NLS_SORT = BINARY NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC'  
'NLS_SORT=BINARY NLS_COMP=ANSI'  
'NLS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'  

+ AI and CI variants.

Comment: you could try PUNCTUATION, or WEST_EUROPEAN

Comment: I still have to complete more tests but PUCTUATION looks very promising, thank you very much!

Comment: That's almost it. I still have this little difference: Oracle
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-AV-AP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-AV-SP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-SV-AP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-SV-SP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC10-DV-AP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC10-DV-SP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC2-DV-AP

Ms SQL
0031-CASTOR-BLOC10-DV-AP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC10-DV-SP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-AV-AP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-AV-SP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-SV-AP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC1-SV-SP
0031-CASTOR-BLOC2-DV-AP

Comment: @SébastienBoudreau - please edit your question to include this latest information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found this solution:

```
ORDER BY NLSSORT(COLUMN_NAME, 'NLS_SORT = FRENCH_M')
```

At least in my particular context, i get the same sorting under both MS SQL Server (default sorting) and Oracle.

Here is two useful links:

http://www.myoracleguide.com/xl/Linguistic_Sorting_Frequently_Asked_Questions.htm

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG005

Answer (score 0):

Could consider use of rpad function?

e.g.

```sql
select name, rpad(upper(replace(translate(name,'_','+'),'-','') ),15,'0') as v1
from sorttest order by 
rpad(upper(replace(translate(name,'_','+'),'-','') ),15,'0')
```

Comment: Another approach is to not even try to have Oracle and SQL*Server sort in the same way ...  i.e. change algorithm or approach .. i..e create an upfront array of key values ...    or ... do a SQL*server lookup for each Oracle source row ...  or vica versa .....  etc.